# How to make image responsive in CSS so that it can fit equally aligned in height with its adjacent text?

Tags: html, css

I have an image in the `<img>` tag with some text in the `<p>` tag. Both are enclosed inside a `<div>`.

Though the image is responsive and resized in equal aspect ratio when the browser window is resized, but having one annoying issue which is that when resizing browser window, as the text is wrapped to multiple lines below, the image becomes small in height to its adjacent text. It makes my site design ugly. How can I make image equal in height to its neighbor text in resized window.

Please note that when the browser window is resized less than 768px, the image and text block both receives width of 100% and they are stacked over each other.

Please look at the screenshots given below to clearly understand my problem. In first picture, you can see the blank space below the image - that's my issue. I want to stretch image till baseline of the last line of my text but keeping aspect ratio intact.

**Current Issue:**

[image]

**My Requirement:**

[image]

**EDIT**

Please note that having HTML `width` and `height` attributes in the `<img>` tag doesn't matter. It doesn't change the dimension of the image if CSS rules associated with image dimensions are written.

Also I can't remove these HTML `width` and `height` attributes from every image if the content is coming from `WYSIWYG`. It won't be feasible and possible if I am not the person who is producing this content.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

.container {
  max-width:1200px;
  border:1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.col {
  width:100%;
  float:left;
  padding:15px;
}

.container {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    width:25%;
  }

  .right {
    width:75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="col left">
    <img src="images/nature.jpg" width="640" height="480" />
  </div>
<div class="col right">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare nec ac lectus. Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: width, object-fit + flex should help. have you tryed that instead float ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I know `object-fit` but don't know usage of `flex`. Btw, `tryed` shouldn't be written as `tried`?

Answer (score 1):

here is the flex/width/object-fit idea :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .left {
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
  }
  .left img {
    position: absolute;    /* take it of the flow, so it doesn't stretch the parent if    col right is shorter */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 0 0 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/640/480" width="640" height="480" />
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
    <h1>PLZ, run in fullpage mode , then resized</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum
      et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare nec ac lectus.
      Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum
      et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

display:table version :

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-)layout: fixed;
  }
  .left {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    flex: 0 0 30%;
  }
  .left img {
    position: absolute;
    /* take it of the flow, so it doesn't stretch the parent if    col right is shorter */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  .right {
    padding-left: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1041/640/480" width="640" height="480" />
  </div>
  <div class="col right">
    <h1>PLZ, run in fullpage mode , then resized</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum
      et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare nec ac lectus.
      Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum
      et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't we do it without `flex` and just with `float` which is what my current layout is based on?

Comment: No, alternative can be display:grid or table/table-cell. This is not the purpose of float

Comment: I can go with `table/table-cell` option without any problem as I know how to handle all these.

Comment: Okay. Update and add the display properties, but keep position for .left and img ;)  `.container{display:table;width:100%;table-)layout:fixed;}  .left{display:table-cell;width:25%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1 : Try making `height = 100%`

Solution #2 : Use `display: flex;` on the parent div of `left` and `right` column

like so :

```html
<div class="container" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="left col">
    <img src="myimage" style="height:100%" />
  </div>
  <div class="right col">...my content..</div>
</div>
```

Make sure to give `<img>` height 100% ,  If it is in another `div`

Comment: I think you are suggesting me wrong advice. Inclusion of `<img>` `width` and `height` doesn't make any difference. The CSS rules on the image will override these HTML attributes. Also if we give `<img>` a width of `100%` then it will be stretched more than its original width when the browser window is resized, making image distorted. The height should be set as `auto` to keep aspect ratio of image.

Comment: @Sachin okay.., height 100% would be enough then. setting height to auto will keep the aspect ratio . which is not helpful as you need it to be stretched till the content.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve it. I made some changes to the HTML I hope that's okay.
Here is a working example if that's not what you are looking for please let me know.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

.container {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.h-100 {
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .right {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="inner-wrapper col left">
      <div class="h-100 row">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-wrapper col right">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus.
          Vestibulum et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare
          nec ac lectus. Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo
          auctor ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu
          mauris purus. Vestibulum et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi
          egestas ornare nec ac lectus. Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo
          auctor ex.tae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum et nisl
          ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare nec ac lectus. Nullam
          urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex.tae viverra mattis, imperdiet
          nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. Nunc ultricies, augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque
          nec ligula ut tortor convallis ultricies sed vel leo. Nullam congue ligula sed lectus viverra rhoncus. Nullam tincidunt nibh sed ligula maximus faucibus. Nunc eu mauris purus. Vestibulum et nisl ut massa finibus laoreet in sit amet tortor. Suspendisse
          non leo quam. Ut consectetur dictum nibh vel vehicula. Vestibulum lobortis purus quam, id mattis purus sollicitudin volutpat. Maecenas ut libero in nisi egestas ornare nec ac lectus. Nullam urna nisi, rhoncus vitae viverra mattis, imperdiet
          nec velit. Aenean libero elit, luctus id maximus at, congue eget tortor. augue eget facilisis luctus, nisl nibh aliquet libero, id ullamcorper ligula leo auctor ex.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

IF that didn't work let me know.

Comment: Not good enough. Your solution breaks my layout. The columns are not stacked on top of each other even when window is resized < 768px. Image also looks distorted.

Comment: Your provided solution also fails when we have multiple paragraphs. Because of `flex` they appear as multiple columns which screws up my design and layout.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML file, you must remove the height and width attributes completely to make the following code work.

The image tag's CSS `height` attribute should have the value of `100%`, not `auto`.

Replace

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

with

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and it should all work.

Comment: Sorry buddy, you are also wrong here. Making height 100% doesn't make any difference. Doesn't solve my problem either. I don't think you have practically tried it yourself before writing here. Also inline html width and height attributes don't ruin the image dimension. If the html is produced by a wysiwyg, then who will remove these attributes from all the html manually? It will be tedious, time consuming and infeasible.